# What are the coordinates of a point given its distance from another point?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

If the abscissa of a point is twice the value of the ordinate and has a distance of $2\sqrt{17}$ units from the point $(4,-5)$, what are the coordinates of the point?

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: Right now i'm trying to use different methods like using the distance formula etc.

Comment: Or please just give me a formula that I can use please. It would help me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Let your point be $(x,y)$  The first sentence gives you a relationship between $x$ and $y$. Then write the formula for the distance between $(x,y)$ and $(4,-5)$ and set it equal to $2 \sqrt{17}$.  You now have two equations in two unknowns.